# Relationship between eigenvectors of $B^{-1}A$ and $B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2}$ where $A, B$ are symmetric positive definite?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

If $A$ and $B$ are symmetric, positive definite matrices in $\mathbb{R}^{nxn}$, what is the relationship between the eigenvectors of $B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2}$ and $B^{-1}A$?

I have shown they have the same eigenvalues by proving that $B^{-1}A$ and $AB^{-1}$ have the same eigenvalues, but I'm not sure about the relationships between the eigenvectors of $B^{-1}A$ and $B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2}$.

Comment: Are you familiar with how a *similarity* transformation (which will preserve *eigenvalues*) affects *eigenvectors*?

Comment: @hardmath I am not, care to share a bit more?

Comment: If $Au = \lambda u$, then $B^{-1}AB$ will have eigenvector $B^{-1}u$ corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Comment: @hardmath So we are saying that if $B^{-1}Aw=\lambda w$, then $B^{1/2}B^{-1}AB^{-1/2}=B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2}$ has eigenvector $B^{-1/2}w$. Is that right?

Comment: You are close, but check the algebra.  It's $B^{1/2} w$ that makes that work.

Comment: Ah I see--thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

If
$$
B^{-1}Av=\lambda v\ ,
$$
then multiplying both sides by $\ B^\frac{1}{2}\ $ gives
$$
B^{-\frac{1}{2}}Av=\lambda B^\frac{1}{2}v\ .
$$
So what is
$$
B^{-\frac{1}{2}}AB^{-\frac{1}{2}}\big(B^\frac{1}{2}v\big)\ \Big(=B^\frac{1}{2}B^{-1}AB^{-\frac{1}{2}}\big(B^\frac{1}{2}v\big)\ \Big)\ ?
$$